# how to use moment's isBefore with dates as Strings?

Tags: momentjs

I have two strings that I'd like to compare as dates using moment's 'isBefore'. I tried this:

```
//doc.id = '18-08-2020'
//tomorrowDate = '21-07-2020'
const convertedItem = moment(doc.id, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
              if (moment(tomorrowDate).isBefore(convertedItem)) //should yield true
                   ...
```

Comment: What is the output of what you tried?

Comment: the output I get is ```false```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the format of both `tomorrowDate` and `doc.id` as 'dd-mm-yyyy'

```
 moment(tomorrowDate, 'dd-mm-yyyy').isBefore(moment(doc.id, 'dd-mm-yyyy'))
```

Comment: This worked when I capitalized the formatting. Thanks!

Comment: If you'll have issues like that in the future, you can play with moment.js in the dev tools console on https://momentjs.com/.